# HTTP 403 when data uri post used as value

Tags: php, apache, http-status-code-403, data-uri

experiencing HTTP 403 when trying to post values containing `data:`...

This only happens on 1/4 servers the app was tested on.

code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {
  // some code here..
}

$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG...';
?>

<form name="sendform" method="post">
  <input type="text" value="<?php echo $data; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit" name="send" value="send"/>
</form>
```

Not sure how to solve this... 
any idea why it happens?

Comment: Check for any content filtering that would run on top of Apache. Also, is it related to the structure of the posted data only, or to the size of the request? In other words, does a small `data:` value ends up with a 403 as well?

Comment: Yes, even if i just post the `data:` as is it gives the 403...

Comment: Definitely a firewall / application level filter in play then. Check with your hosting provider

Comment: @capsule you are provably right, seems like it's related to network firewall. to make it work for now I just add the `data` part later using php `explode`

Answer (score 0):

that occurs because it is a security policy that is defined by the hosting provider, that block your request when you sent a request with some POST payload that has `data:image/png;base64,`

In my case, I contact the support team of the hosting provider, they have root access and can whitelist the rule.

change that rule affect the hosting security level. but always can switch back that rule requesting it to the support team